# Merge commits of one repo to another one

Tags: git, github, version-control

I know it's an unfortunate setup, but I have two Repos:

1.) ***Repo A*** is the base Repo, which is a project used as the base for other projects.

2.) **Repo B**, from which I forked ***Repo A*** and made modifications.

In the meantime ***Repo A*** gets some new features and updates.

Now I want to update **Repo B** to take over the new changes and updates of ***Repo A***, but keep my modifications.

I could now create a new Branch from **Repo B** with the forked newest version of *Repo A*. And then I could manually copy paste my modifications to it.

But this is of course error sensitive and takes time. Is there a way to first identify my commits and modifications, I have made to **Repo B**, and let Git merge the changes to my newly forked Branch based on *Repo A*?

I guess cherry picking is a bit tedious, because it would go through all commits, even though, they aren't the latest. So maybe one diff, which shows the difference between **Repo B** and the *Repo A* to the time I forked it, and make it possible to merge this diff?

Comment: You definitely need ro stop thinking in terms of repos for things that are related to **branches**. You don't merge.... or cherry-pick.... or rebase _repos_. Those are operations you perform on branches. Would you mind editing your question so that you speak of repos and branches where appropriate?

Comment: Well that's exactly my problem, I don't have to branches, I have two different Repos. And somehow I need to identify, the diff between Repo B and the base Repo A at the time I forked/copied it, save this somehow, create a new branch with the code of the current state of Repo A and apply the diff, meaning the commits.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple remote repositories for each local repository. What I would do is go your local checkout of Repo B, and add remote Repo A as one of its remote repositories. Doing this would enable the local Repo B to pull the changes from either the remote Repo A or remote Repo B.

```
git remote add <name> <clone url>
ex: git remote add RepoA https...
```

Your local Repo B can then pull the changes from remote Repo A. but instead of origin, you specify the remote branch. In this case its RepoA.

```
git pull <name>/<branch name>
ex: git pull RepoA/master
```

Comment: This is a good idea. But I do have the problem, that RepoA actually has so many changes, that I will receive tons of merge conflicts on files I even didn't touch.